# How to get percentage from SQL query using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT hotel, SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights) AS 'total weekend night' 
FROM hotel_bookings
GROUP BY hotel;
```

| hotel | total_weekend_nights | total_week_nights |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City Hotel | 63082 | 173174 |
| Resort Hotel | 47664 | 125337 |

I want to show the results from above as as a percentage rather than the numbers you see. I tried using:

```
SELECT
    hotel, 
    stays_in_weekend_nights * 100/ SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights) OVER() 'Percentage'
```

However, that only gives me the percentage of each individual booking which is not what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking for % of weekend nights vs week nights by hotel?  Or % of weekend nights and week nights across the total over all hotels?  Can you show your desired results in table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written gives the percentage of the referenced ***column***.

If you want the percentage of the ***row***, you have to explicitly state which columns you're adding together.

```
SELECT
  hotel,
  SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights) AS [total weekend night],
  SUM(stays_in_week_nights) AS [total week night],
  SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights) * 100.0 / SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights) AS [% weekend night],
  SUM(stays_in_week_nights) * 100.0 / SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights) AS [% week night]
FROM
  hotel_bookings
GROUP BY
  hotel;
```

You can avoid some repetition with sub-queries or common table expressions...

```
WITH
  totals AS
(
  SELECT
    hotel,
    SUM(stays_in_weekend_nights) AS [total weekend night],
    SUM(stays_in_week_nights)    AS [total week night]
  FROM
    hotel_bookings
  GROUP BY
    hotel
)
SELECT
  *,
  [total weekend night] * 100.0 / ([total week night] + [total weekend night])   AS [% weekend night],
  [total week night]    * 100.0 / ([total week night] + [total weekend night])   AS [% week night]
FROM
  totals
```

There may even be other *(better)* options, if you show us what the originating data looks like.